# Animating several consecutive UILabels at the same speed at the same time to the same point

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have 5 consecutive `UILabel` like this:

[image]

They were created with the same frame than the label `1` and then were moved using a `CGAffineTransform` property. So a `CGAffineTransformIdentity` will bring them all back on top of label `1`.

I would like, when I press a button, to move them all back to the label `1`, at the same speed and once they reach their destination, remove them from their superview.

So far I've done like the following but it doesn't work:

```
var reversedLabels = getLabels().reverse()
let duration: NSTimeInterval = 5
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
    for (index, label) in enumerate(reversedLabels) {
        let relativeDuration: NSTimeInterval = duration * Double(index) / Double(reversedLabels.count)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(relativeDuration, animations: {
            label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }, completion: { finished in
                label.hidden = true
        })
    }
    }, completion: { finished in
        for (index, label) in enumerate(reversedLabels) {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }
})
```

The completion of the main animation gets called before the completions of the nested animations. Then I guess it's not the way to do it.

How would you do it? (and why the "final" completion isn't called at the very end?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not animating any animatable property of any view inside first animation block, the completion block will get executed immediately after animation start. What I cant understand is why do you need that block at all. In completion of inner animations you are hiding your labels, which is the same UI behaviour as removing them from superview, so maybe this block of code (without outer animation) might bring to you the desired result

```
for (index, label) in enumerate(reversedLabels) {

    let relativeDuration: NSTimeInterval = duration * Double(index) / Double(reversedLabels.count)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(relativeDuration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {

            label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }, completion: {finished in
            label.removeFromSuperview()=
        })
}
```

EDITED : `relativeDuration` should be calculating by adding +1 to index otherwise first animation will have 0 duration. Also to achieve same speed for all animations you should use `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear`

Comment: ok I understand why it went straight to the completion block. The problem with doing it with the inner block only is that they all start together (which is fine), but they all go to the same spot (which is fine) in the same amount of time, so with different speeds.

Comment: I still don't clearly understand your requirements. Do you want to first start animation label 5 and after label 5 is on top of label 4 start animation label 4 to top of label 3 ?

Comment: No, I want to start all of them together and end each one of them once they are on top of label 1. But I want them to have the same speed, like if 5 was following 4 which was following 3 and so on. But with this block, as the duration is the same but the distances are different, 5 will go faster than 4 which will go faster than 3 and so on.

Comment: Actually adding +1 creates a small shift in the animation, they don't move exactly at the same speed, plus the first animation with a duration of 0 is what I'm looking for. Thanks, `.CurveLinear` work. I didn't know about it.

Comment: Removed +1, I tried your example with 5 labels but only 4 of them were in array and thats why +1 was needed